# Xml Representation of the flowchart

Tags: xml

Is there anyone who has an idea of how I can convert flowchart to xml? I need an xml representation of the flowchart. The example of a very simple flowchart will help me get started.

Comment: It would help to provide the flowchart you would like to see represented by XML, since XML can represent just about anything. If you get more specific, we might be able to give advice for your specific need.

Comment: I just need the flowchart to be represented in xml such that i can get the same understanding of the problem from reading xml file instead of looking at the flow chart. That is the xml should be the direct translation of the flowchart.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't see how to attach a file here. I wanted to show you the flowchart

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as if you're looking for GraphML, GXL, or a similar XML vocabulary; any of them is likely to do a reasonable job of representing a flowchart in XML.